# Why word refactor was chosen for change of program or its part?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, ide, refactoring

My question is partly liguistic, but very related to programming (of almost anything, web pages or anything else).

I would like to know **why word *refactor* was chosen for changing of program or its part**, if else word probably would be more exact and better describing done change.

IDEs (for example NetBeans or Eclipse) use this word only for renaming of any part of chosen program (project), including moving of file to else place (from view of any OS it is probably only renaming).

But renaming is not about changing of *factor* (because it is something that is not changed when it is renamed).

Closer to meaning of word *refactor* (as changing of factor) is *manual* rewriting of any part, when rewritten part has changed behaviour (but not what program does from outer view - as is written in topic [What is refactoring and what is only modifying code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025844/what-is-refactoring-and-what-is-only-modifying-code)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "Refactoring" is derived from mathematics where you find an equivalent expression by applying factoring again. The equivalent expression does not change the final outcome but it is much easier to understand, use, or reuse.

There are many refactoring techniques and renaming is one of them. Other techniques include extract method, extract class, move method, move class, pull/push method to super/sub-class and many more.

Comment: I will wait until Sunday, if somebody would give any other answer - and then you will get your _answer reward_.